# Handle google talk message using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xmpp, google-talk

Is there any library that allows to handle google talk messages using Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://home.gna.org/xmpp4r/

Answer (score 2):

[Blather](http://rubygems.org/gems/blather) is an XMPP library using EventMachine and Nokogiri.