# Facebook chat with pure ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook

I was just wondering, if there's any gem I could use for facebook chat. I don't want to use Rails. I'm trying to build a command-line application to use on linux.

Thanks. :)

Comment: See [Handle google talk message using Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880276/handle-google-talk-message-using-ruby).  Google Talk and Facebook Chat both use the XMPP protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook chat provides a **Jabber/XMPP** service, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

You have to look for a gem that supports XMPP, for example [xmpp4r](https://github.com/ln/xmpp4r).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem https://github.com/kissrobber/xmpp4r_facebook. There is a sample usage in README file. It worked very well for me.